# Does python store one value for an int and many references?

Tags: python, reference

I'm wondering why this evaluates to `True`.

```
x = 1
if x is 1:
    print "Does x and 1 point to the same object?"
    print "Does this mean python doesn't store redundant values?"
```

It doesn't work for this case as I expect.

```
x = range(10)
y = range(10)
if not x is y:
    print "I expect this"
```

My understanding is that `is` checks to see if two names are pointing to the same object.  Does this imply that python has a mechanism to avoid creating redundant values?

Comment: Between -5 and 256, yes, they are literally the same object depending on the implementation of Python

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the result of `is`. It is perfectly reasonable for python to optimize *immutable* built-in types. `is` is the **only** operator that affects the result, so this doesn't really break much. However this is done only for a few types because most of the objects created by a program fall into specific categories that should be optimized (e.g. integers, lists, dictionaries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an implementation detail of the CPython interpreter, but integers with small values are "interned" -- whenever the result of an expression falls within a certain range, an existing int object with the same value is returned.

You could check the range that gets interned by using the following code:

```
interned_range = [i for i in range(-1000, 1000) if i+0 is i]
print min(interned_range), max(interned_range)
```

My CPython inters integers between -5 and 256 inclusive.

Being an implementation detail, this behaviour should generally not be relied upon.

Comment: in CPython 3.7, why does `max(interned_range)` returns a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`?